# TypeError: Cannot find function replace in object 9. (line 51, file "main")

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to set up an okr tree from spreadsheet based on the following [project](https://qiita.com/tanabee/items/3c17dcdbb8efb7afe212), but I get an error in 1 of the functions:

```
function arrayToObj(array) {
  return {                     //error in this line
    id: array[0],
    name: array[1],
    title: '<p class="okr-label">O</p><p class="okr-text">' + array[3].replace(/\n/g, '<br>') + '</p><p class="okr-label">KR</p>' + array[4].replace(/\n/g, '<br>'),
  }
}
```

> TypeError: Cannot find function replace in object 9. (line 51, file
>   "main")

Comment: You're trying to use `string.replace()` on a number. Have you tried converting it to a string first?